# Drop duplicates with less precision

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with string-columns and float columns I would like to use `drop_duplicates` to remove duplicates. Some of the duplicates are not exactly the same, because there are some slight differences in low decimal places. How can I remove duplicates with less precision?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'text': ['aaa','aaa','aaa','bb'], 'result': [1.000001,1.000000,2,2]})
df
     result text
0  1.000001  aaa
1  1.000000  aaa
2  2.000000  aaa
3  2.000000   bb
```

I would like to get

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'text': ['aaa','aaa','bb'], 'result': [1.000001,2,2]})
df_out
     result text
0  1.000001  aaa
1  2.000000  aaa
2  2.000000   bb
```

Comment: Binning is an overcomplicated solution for this problem, but I'll share a link anyway: https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_binning_data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `round` with a given precision in order to round your df.

> DataFrame.round(decimals=0, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Round a DataFrame to a variable number of decimal places.

For example you can apply the round with two decimals by this:

```
df = df.round(2)
```

Also you can apply it on specific columns, for example:

```
df = df.round({'result': 2})
```

After the rounding you can use the function `drop_duplictes`

Answer (score 3):

round them

```
df.loc[df.round().drop_duplicates().index]

     result text
0  1.000001  aaa
2  2.000000  aaa
3  2.000000   bb
```

Comment: Thanks. putting 1 or `PRECISION` or something like that as an argument to `round()` might make your answer more useful, or more quickly, for many readers.

Comment: I think this works just because `keep='first'` is the default in drop_duplicates; the result would be different if rows 0 and 1 were swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.trunc` to get at the precision you are looking for.  Use `pandas` `duplicated` to find which ones to keep.

```
df[~df.assign(result=np.trunc(df.result.values * 100)).duplicated()]
```